# How to execute a page or application on startup WebCgiRole on Windows Azure

Tags: azure, startup, fastcgi

How can I execute a PHP page or an application when WebCgiRole starts on Windows Azure?

Comment: Are you trying to just launch a default page? Or run an actual startup task for the role?

Comment: I want to run an actual startup task for the role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two methods of executing startup tasks. The "old school" method was to include the task as part of the role's OnStart method. This could be done either by imbedding the functionality into the RoleEntryPoint's OnStart or by shelling out to run a batch file or powershell script. However, this approach requires you to be able to make alterations to what's essentially a .NET managed code class. Something that may not be optimal in your php based environment.

The second approach is a new one that's available via the 1.3 SDK releast that came out at PDC10. Its using the new start-up tasks that are available via the service configuration. Wade Wegner, a member of the development team, has a nice blog post that discusses using this feature. In a nuthsell, with it you can then run those start-up batch or powershell commands without having to modify the OnStart event in managed code.

http://www.wadewegner.com/category/startup-task/

Now the challenge for you may be that your start-up task is defined in a PHP script. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any solid examples for this and my PHP skills are admittedly pretty limited. But it might yet be do-able. Hopefully the information at Wade's blog will at least be enough to get you going in the right directino. :)

Comment: Thanks but in PHP fastCGI role we don't have .NET code to write to on OnStart method. I will try the second method but it seems too complicated. Is this the only way to about it? Because what I actually want to do is to copy some PHP files from a blob storage to a machine when it starts running for the first time.

Comment: Not being a PHP guru, I really can't speak to how you would go about running the PHP script via one of the new startup tasks. It may be entirely possible, its just not somethign I can speak to first hand.